How to speed up boot in Raspberry Pi 3 Model B?
I installed a Raspberry Pi os Lite (64-bit) on a current 32gb SD card and connected it via HDMI.
After that, I'm testing by installing pyqt via apt and running the test.py file.
Since it is CLI mode, I need an xserver, so I installed xorg and openbox packages.
[ nano ~/.bashrc ]
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ "$(tty)" = /dev/tty1 ]; then
    startx
fi

[ nono ~/.xinitrc ]
exec openbox-session

[ nono ~/.config/openbox/autostart ]
python /home/pi/test.py

point in time when the test.py is running is a total of 30 seconds.
Is there anything else I can do or do that I can try?
What we tried to speed up
[ boot/firmware/cmdline.txt ]
rootwait quiet loglevel=3 consoleblank=0 fsck.mode=skip nousb
Systemd-Analyzed Blame Reporting Unused Services and Time-Consuming Services
bluetooth.service / networking.service / NetworkManager.service and reboot.
[ /etc/fstab ]
Minimize filesystem access with noatime in the mount settings.
[ journalctl -b ]
Reduced the time from the first 29:29 to the last boot of 29:45 to 16 seconds.
I've heard that the boot speed can be reduced to a minimum if you want to, but I'd like to make it a little faster.
When you boot up, you want the first screen to be test.py screen, and you want it to boot faster.
Is there anything else I can do or try other than the one I tried?

That's right, I want test.py to appear on the screen when I first boot the Raspberry Pi. Currently, systemd-analyze kernel 5s service 7s takes a total of 11 seconds, but it actually takes 30 seconds. I want to know how to make Raspberry Pi boot faster.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
